# Should subrepos and mercurial-subrepos tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tags:

- [mercurial-subrepos](/questions/tagged/mercurial-subrepos)- 52 questions
- [subrepos](/questions/tagged/subrepos)- 71 questions

Currently the contents of subrepos refers only to the Mercurial flavor, though it appears other VCS' have similar concepts, like `git`'s submodules.

There are 70 questions tagged [mercurial-subrepos](/questions/tagged/mercurial-subrepos) and [subrepos](/questions/tagged/subrepos). There are 19 questions tagged [mercurial](/questions/tagged/mercurial) [subrepos](/questions/tagged/subrepos) [mercurial-subrepos](/questions/tagged/mercurial-subrepos). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7702638/344286) was the only question tagged [subrepos](/questions/tagged/subrepos) without [mercurial](/questions/tagged/mercurial) (I just changed it to [git-submodules](/questions/tagged/git-submodules)).

It seems like the questions with the [subrepos](/questions/tagged/subrepos) tag should have it removed/updated to [mercurial-subrepos](/questions/tagged/mercurial-subrepos), and [subrepos](/questions/tagged/subrepos) should be blocked/aliased to [mercurial-subrepos](/questions/tagged/mercurial-subrepos).